# Bootstrap option text truncating long text on osx chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and when my system tries to display a very long text in the select box, the option text gets truncated (but the element is displayed with the right width). This happens only in Google Chrome for OS X.

**The Code (http://jsfiddle.net/arthurvasconcelos/h21n6Lwx/):**

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <select class="form-control">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="0">65a073e6-066b-11e6-b512-3e1d05defe78_21e23745-838b-44bc-b639-eb02bd04f41f_really_big_name_for_a_option</option>
          <option value="1">82e027b3-a9f1-4274-8056-a3fe67a1f83d_option_test_long_name</option>
          <option value="2">shortter</option>
          <option value="3">short test</option>
          <option value="4">normal test</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Screenshot on Linux:**

[image]

**Screenshot on OSX:**

[image]

Comment: This is not happening with my Chrome on OS X

Comment: @Yuri I have tested with chrome versions 49.0.2623.110 (64-bit), 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit) and 50.0.2661.75 (64-bit) running on El Capitan (10.11.1). In this cases the bug occurred. What is your version?

Comment: It is 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit) on El Capitan (10.11.3). As you can see [here](http://s31.postimg.org/a6h4zo82j/Screenshot_2016_04_20_17_11_03.png) I loaded the page with resized window and pushed to right side of screen, it still displays the full text